# Duplicate detection with NServiceBus on Azure Service Buus

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus as an abstraction layer for Azure Service Bus (in case we move away from Azure).  I find that when working with multiple subscribers (who subscribe to the same events) the number of duplicate messages increases.  I know Azure Service Bus (ASB) has a way of detecting these duplicates and I can see that the feature is configurable through NServiceBus (according to documentation).  However, I can only get a sample of of achieving duplication detection by means of configuration section.  What I require is a sample of how to achieve this with code.

Thanks

Suraj

Comment: What version of NServiceBus and Azure Service Bus transport are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify configuration using code-based approach as well. NServiceBus has to contracts that can help with that `IConfigurationSource` and `IProvideConfiguration<T>`. Here's [an example](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing-extensibility) how you can take a configuration file section (`UnicastBusConfig`) and specify values via code.

Specifically to what you've asked, implementing `IProvideConfiguration<AzureServiceBusQueueConfig>` will allow you [configure ASB transport](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/configuration/azureservicebusqueueconfig), specifying duplicates and such.

The observation about number of duplicates increasing as a result of increasing subscribers feels as a symptom, not the problem. That is probably a different question, not related to the configuration. Saying that, I'd look into it prior to enabling the native de-dupplication. While you can specify `RequiresDuplicateDetection` and `DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow` be aware that ASB performing duplicate detection on the ID property only. Also, it is better to build your handlers as idempotent, rather than relying on the native de-duplication.

Comment: Hi Sean,  Thank you for your help and advice.